# Obtener valores en un rango de fecha dadas

Tags: python, django

Dado un nombre y dos fechas entradas por parámetro, quisiera hacer una consulta donde tome todos los valores de dicho nombre en ese rango de fecha.

Conozco la manera siguiente de comparar en Django pero esta es estricto y me gustaría tomar las fechas `>=` y `<=`. Esta es la forma que conozco:

```
listuser.filter(day__lt=fechafinal_)
```

Y:

```
listuser.filter(day__gt=fechafinal_)
```

¿Existirá una para mi caso?

Comment: Hola Eric, no queda muy claro lo que preguntas, ¿podrías poner un poco más de código y formatearlo para que quede bien representado en la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer una consulta entre un rango de fechas puedes usar el lookup[`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#range):

```
listuser.filter(
    day__range=(fecha_inicial, fecha_final)
)
```

Ten en cuenta que `range` es inclusivo, es decir, la consulta anterior es equivalente a:

```
listuser.filter(
    day__gte=fecha_inicial, 
    day__lte=fecha_final 
)
```

Comment: Si quiere hacer una lista puede usar la funcion `annotate` o `values_list`, gracias a ellas he podido rendir en mi trabajo, gracias al maestro @César.